# Logistic regression of large dataset

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

I need to build a logistic regression model to do some predictions. However, the dataset is very large, consisting of about 500,000 rows.

For example, if we are going to build a model on whether they are rich people or not, then we code yes as 1 and no as 0 to create a binary response variable and independent variables are gender, age and whether they obtained MBA degree or not. So in this large data set, we have known certainly that 500 people are rich (say they have net worth more than 1 million), and the rest of them are unknown. If I built a logistic regression using this dataset, and try to find those predicted as 1(rich people) but actually they are 0(non-rich people) in the given dataset. Is it correct to use the whole dataset to build a model and use that model to predict the whole group and set the cutoff value very high to identify those people who are actually rich(predicted as 1) but shown as non-rich(0 in the data set)?

Any hints on how to deal with a large dataset when building a logistic regression model, and especially when you only have few response variables marked as 1?

Comment: Isn't you binary variable indicating if a person is known to be rich or not known to be rich, (i.e. rich or don't know). Not if they are rich or not.

Comment: Thanks! It is like that, 1 indicating rich and 0 indicating unknown, sorry for the confusion

Comment: It could be that all the 1/2 million people are rich and while your independent variables are sensible for predicting wealth they are probably not good variables for predicting knowledge of wealth. The 500 could just be those who have had a recent divorce.

Comment: Well I guess I have to distinguish those certainly non-rich people from unknown group then...

Comment: In such cases, the metric to analyse to say the model is good enough to predict whether or not a new person is rich or not is F Ratio and the other two metrics are precision and recall.  Sparse data calls for looking at these metrics against Accuracy Ratio and False positive rate.

Comment: @satishramanathan Thanks a lot, but what I find struggling is, when dealing with logistic regression with large dataset, is it a better way to construct it? say like doing some data transformation? or do you know any reference?